# re size datafile oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, datafile, sysdba

thanks for reading.

I am currently working with an Oracle 11G.I have a problem with a tablespace, I have very little space left, and I need to increase its capacity.I know what to do with this command:

```
alter tablespace datafile '+DG_DATA/sificore/datafile/auditoria.282.999190187' resize 160000m;
```

But when I'm trying to find the dbf, it appears to me like this.

[image]

My question is this:

I can't find the file with the dbf extension, can I run the command with what appears to me there (+ DG_DATA / sificore / datafile / audit.282.999190187) and would it have no problem?

the database, is currently in active redolog mode, would it have conflicts?

Should I do the issue of putting it in online, offline and recover datafile mode?

Thanks for reading, I will greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The database is using Oracle Automated Storage Management, so the data files are not located in a normal file system where you can "cd" to the directory and see them. You would need to have privileges within the ASM management database and use a tool like "asmcmd" to see more information. As long as the database recognizes the file as online, you are fine. You do not need to take anything offline or jump through any other hoops. See this link for more info: http://www.oracle-wiki.net/startdocsusefuloraclecommands